# Excel VBA open and interact with external program with dependencies

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which needs to open an external program and execute a function in that program. This is a program which can only be communicated with externally using SendKeys.

The problem is, the program has multiple dependant .exe files which it calls upon. When I use

```
Program = Shell(ProgramPath, 1)
AppActivate Program
```

I can send over commands with SendKeys, but once I try to execute the run command from the program it fails at finding the dependant .exe files which the program needs to run. All the files and the spreadsheet are located in the same directory. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect it it might have something to do with where its trying to find the files.  If you can start the external application normally ( as in going to the app directory and running the app) then chances are using the Shell method is setting the default Path to be either the path of the workbook or MSExcel,  and the App is using the default path, to find its external programs.

Comment: So the external program can't find its own dependencies? This sounds like not a VBA problem... If it's as @NathanFisher supposes, you can try changing the Current Working Directory of the shell object like [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156586.aspx).

Comment: How do you normally start the program?  Are you using a shortcut, and does that shortcut pass any parameters to the program?

Comment: that was it, @NathanFisher, I was using a relative path to specify the program path. Adding in a chdir to the base directory before the shell  solved the issue. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the comment as an Answer ...

I suspect it it might have something to do with where its trying to find the files. If you can start the external application normally ( as in going to the app directory and running the app) then chances are using the Shell method is setting the default Path to be either the path of the workbook or MSExcel, and the App is using the default path, to find its external programs